# Why do we have to use GoogleMap.snapshot() to capture snapshots of maps?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-view, android-mapview

v2 of the Google Maps APIs expose a [`snapshot`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#snapshot(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback)) method for obtaining Bitmap representations of `GoogleMap` objects as they appear in our UI.

This method is definitely *required*: for instance, if I try to manually create a Bitmap representation of my entire application UI as follows:

```
View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
view.draw(canvas);
```

the map is not captured (the corresponding pixels in `bitmap` are all black).

However, if I include a `MapView` in my `Activity` layout, and then inspect the view hierarchy at runtime using [Stetho](https://github.com/facebook/stetho), it appears that at least part of the `MapView` (probably overlays) is rendered using an internal hierarchy of 'regular' `View`s, like `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `ImageView`, etc.:

[image: A textual representation of an example app view hierarchy inspected at runtime]

My question is: **what's different about the `MapView`? Why does drawing to a `Canvas` not capture any part of the map at all** (not even the 'regular' views used to render parts of it)**?**

For reference, the implementation I gave above can successfully capture `SurfaceView` contents, as well as all other 'regular' views.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, they are [using `setSecure()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setSecure%28boolean%29) on the `SurfaceView` that is the map.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I am familiar with setting `FLAG_SECURE` on a `Window`, which does _not_ prevent "screenshot capture" using the method in the original question. That seems intended to prevent screenshots using hardware buttons, and to prevent sensitive information from appearing in recent task previews. This should be easy to test; I'll give it a try and report back.

How are you deducing that the map is presented using a `SurfaceView`, by the way? Should I expect to see a `SurfaceView` in the hierarchy above? The `MapView` class extends `FrameLayout` directly.

Comment: @stkent: "Should I expect to see a SurfaceView in the hierarchy above?" -- no, they subclassed it. I was trying to figure out how to have maps in a `ViewPager`, with the horizontal swipe over the map sent to the map, not the `ViewPager`. This requires overriding `canScroll()` in the pager, and determining whether the touch events are over the map. The map responds (or at least used to respond) to `instanceof SurfaceView`. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/MapsV2/Pager/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/mapsv2/pager/MapAwarePager.java

Comment: Hmm, if I try to use that same check now (v8.4.0 of Play Services) I get the 'Inconvertible types' error.

Comment: @stkent: That doesn't mean that they're not using a `SurfaceView` subclass in there. It just means that the `View` passed into `canScroll()` is no longer just that `SurfaceView`. And it means that I need to update a book sample, apparently. :-)

Comment: Haha, yes, that mysterious `com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.eh` class could contain who-knows-what.

Comment: Ok, I tried creating a `SurfaceView` with a colored background, marking it secure, and then adding to the view hierarchy. It doesn't show in screenshots captured using the method above, but it also doesn't show at runtime! Mysterious, but I agree, plausible that something similar to your suggestion is going on here.